# Left click to select text causes ^C of the current line in git bash?

Tags: git, git-bash

When I left click mouse to select text in git bash, it always produces a ^+C and begins a new line. How to fix it?

My OS is 64-bit win10 and the version of git is 2.10.2-64-bit. The information about git bash is as follow.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe my Git Bash also behaves this way.  I usually use:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>INSERT</kbd>

instead to paste something from the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

For me if i right click on Git Bash am able to get the paste option (in windows 8.1). but in windows 10 just right click is enough to paste. or else you can right click on the top of the Git Bash go to edit and paste.